# Why would piece of content of each content type be migrated but their text formats wrong?

Tags: 6, migrations

I'm trying to migrate content D6 -> D7. I've written the importers (actually just edited existing ones) and run the process. However, as far as I can see, body of content are imported but with the wrong format i.e. one of them correctly shows as Full HTML while another shows just Select. [image: text format wrong]

Below is my importer:

```
class StoryMigration extends NodeMigration {
  public function __construct(array $arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'title');
    $this->addFieldMapping('body', 'body');
    $this->addFieldMapping('taxonomy_tags_1', 'field_tags')
      ->defaultValue('tid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_headerimage', 'field_headerimage')
      ->sourceMigration('Files');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_headerimage:file_class')
      ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I also did a format mapping, like below:

```
$common_arguments = array(
    'source_connection' => 'default',
    'source_version' => 6,
    'format_mappings' => array(
      '1' => 'filtered_html',
      '2' => 'full_html',
      '3' => 'php_code'
    ),
   ...
   ...
   ...
  );
```

Comment: I see you extend `NodeMigration` - is this the migrate_d2d module, or the core migrate module? It has been a while since I have seen migrate, but I never used migrate_d2d (preferred to roll my own).

Comment: It's the migrate_d2d module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the body format.

This is from 6 years ago, but reposting in case mikeryan does not see this question.

> if the format is part of the source data (i.e., it varies from node
>   to node), you can make use of the source_field feature:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('body', 'body')
     ->arguments(array('format' => array('source_field' => 'body_format'));
```

Where `body_format` is the value from the source db I believe.

It has been a loooong time since I have done a 6 to 7 migration.

[This post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1942238) might also be of use if you are using migrate_d2d.

Comment: I finally did it. I compared one correctly imported post and one failed. Correct one was Full HTML and failed was Filtered HTML. So I looked at the formats and Filtered HTML wasn't there so I created it. Additionally, I chose to migrate Filtered HTML for both source and destination.